# Comparing a list to each value of dictionary (which are a list of strings)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of drugs that I want to compare to a dictionary, where the dictionary keys are drug codes and the dictionary values are lists of drugs. I'd like to only retain the drugs within the dictionary that correspond to the list of drugs.

---

Example list:

```
l = ['sodium', 'nitrogen', 'phosphorus']
```

And dictionary:

```
d = {'A02A4': ['sodium', 'nitrogen', 'carbon']}
```

---

I would want my final dictionary to look like:

```
{'A02A4': ['nitrogen', 'sodium']}
```

with the value that is not present in the list removed, and to do this for all key, value pairs in the dictionary

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It would be helpful to see what you have already tried, and to know specifically what problems you ran into in your attempt

Comment: @G.Anderson I'm not sure where to even start with this. It would be simple enough with just one value per key, but i'm not sure how to approach this with a list attached to a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary comprehension and [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) to keep only the values that intersect with the list:

```
l = ['sodium', 'nitrogen', 'phosphorus']
d = {'A02A4': ['sodium', 'nitrogen', 'carbon']}

{i: list(set(v) & set(l)) for i,v in d.items()}
{'A02A4': ['nitrogen', 'sodium']}
```

Or equivalently, using [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
{i: list(set(v).intersection(l)) for i,v in d.items()}
{'A02A4': ['nitrogen', 'sodium']}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I realized I also failed to completely normalize my lists, so that was also an issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to accept the answer. Thank you!